# The problem occurs when I connect via ftp via android emulator and try to download files

Tags: android, ftp, emulation

i am download file on my ftp server, but if i using android emulator then sometimes return different error.(File corrupted , Remote prematurely closed connection or auth error) but sometimes is worked perfect.

Example 20 download
5 download success.
2 fail
3 success
2 fail.

Why ?

Can i solved this problem ? What can i do.

Thank you.

Edit:

The problem occurs when I connect via ftp via android emulator and try to download files.

```
      clientFluentFTP.LoadProfile(new FtpProfile
        {
            Host = host,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword),
            Encryption = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit,
            Protocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
            DataConnection = FtpDataConnectionType.PASV,
            Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        });
        clientFluentFTP.ValidateAnyCertificate = true;
        clientFluentFTP.Connect();
        clientFluentFTP.DownloadFile(nereyeindir, "veritabani/" + "xx.zip", FtpLocalExists.Overwrite,  FtpVerify.Throw);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: `download file on my ftp server` What to you mean? Download from ftp server to Android devive? Or upload from Android device to ftp server?

Comment: The problem occurs when I connect via ftp via android emulator and try to download files. @blackapps